# Where can I host my pictures for free without giving up rights?

Tags: legal, web, copyright, presentation

I want to host some pictures at low cost (less than flickr). I have come across [Shareapic](http://www.shareapic.net/index.php) and Imgur. However, imagur strips the meta-data off of uploaded images, and I couldn't find much information on shareapic. Note: I want to retain ownership of my photos so Picasa web-upload won't work.

Comment: You are mistaken about Picassa. _Google claims no ownership or control over any Content submitted, posted or displayed by you on or through Picasa Web Albums._ http://picasa.google.com/intl/en-GB/web/tos.html

Comment: By submitting, posting or displaying Content which is intended to be available to the general public, you grant Google a worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free license to reproduce, adapt, distribute and publish such Content for the purpose of displaying, distributing and promoting Google services.

Comment: That just grants Google use of the image for something, I would wager any albums set as private wouldn't be used. Nobody else would use them, but I imagine it would cover their ability to return them in search results and so on... Flickr is so cheap though, I can't see why you wouldn't just go with that.

Comment: ...especially as Flickr can be completely free...

Comment: That isn't giving up ownership, though. Some of those rights are needed just to be ae to host and dismay the photos. The advertising-use clause isn't something I like, but it's still not giving up ownership. Also, all of those terminate if you remove the images.

Comment: See also: http://www.robertstech.com/blog/?p=327

Answer (score 8):

I recommend Flickr. You can even choose Creative Commons licenses to assign to photos based on what licensing rights you want to permit.

Answer (score 0):

[www.deviantart.com](http://www.deviantart.com)

Answer (score 0):

I use Fotki - less known than some but flexible enough and reasonable features and CHEAP.

You can set licence rights of your choice - they offer various variants of GPL and you can add your own in several says. I use non-commercial use only, no derivates, attribtution and suggest people email me. That does not stop copying but allows you to retain rights. You can password and/or hide albums etc.

In your account settings it says: Copyright holder:
 Set the default copyright message for your account.
 It can be overridden for a particular album or photo

From memory cost is about $US/10 per year if you buy a few years for unlimited storage, high resolution photos (may have a 10 MB limit?) . I think there is a 2 GB/day upload limit. Supports FTP an slideshows (and I seem to know more slideshow settings than any one else in public as I played and then asked them). All up its very good.

I have 90 GB and 119,000+ photos on Fotki at present. That's 'acceptable' [tm] for $10/year.
 [Here](http://j.mp/NZPHOTOS) j.mp/NZPHOTOS

They offer album per photo view, thumbnails, slideshow and a very nice roll view [like this](http://public.fotki.com/RussellMc/atw/rm01/?view=roll#1) - roll down - do not click until you see a photo you want to interact with in some manner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your needs are, but if you are just looking for raw storage, try Amazon's/AWS Simple Storage Service.

It's primarily a paid service, but they have a FREE plan that will start you with 5GB of storage 15 GB transfer out / monthly.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

You'll need to read over the page thoroughly to get a sense of what they offer and how they work, but for what they offer, I think they are worth the effort.